# Using a substring in a PowerShell pipeline

Tags: powershell, pipeline

Is there a possibility to manipulate the items in a pipeline of PowerShell?

In more concrete words: I start my pipeline with an "svn list". This returns me a list of paths in my repository, all directories with a trailing "/". The list of paths should be stored in an array, but without the "/".

This:

```
svn list svn://server/repository/myPath | $_.TrimEnd("/")
```

does not work because [TrimEnd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trimend) is an expression and may not be used within a pipeline.

The result of the pipeline should be something like:

```
$a = @("foo", "bar)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don’t have the SVN stuff to try the same here. But, from what I see, you are missing a [ForEach-Object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/ForEach-Object) (aliases `%` and `foreach`) after the pipe.

Try this

```
svn list svn://server/repository/myPath | ForEach-Object { $_.TrimEnd("/") }
```

or

```
svn list svn://server/repository/myPath | % { $_.TrimEnd("/") }
```

Comment: Thank you. The ForEach-Object was missing!

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
svn list svn://server/repository/myPath | % TrimEnd /
```